# Want to return data in Json format by getting from database Object. Php Symfony

Tags: php, json, symfony, object, doctrine-query

I am getting data from database model and want to return in json format, but it returns empty array, but when i use dump for variable that contains objects data then it return the actual data.

**Here is the code for getting data from object**

```
   $user = $this->getUser();
    $bookings = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Trip::class)
                ->findBy(['customer' => $user], ['id' => 'DESC']);
```

here i return it in json form

```
 return new JsonResponse(['bookings' => $bookings]);
```

It display on screen that array is empty.

[image]

**i use dd to check whether data is comming or not**

```
  $user = $this->getUser();
    $bookings = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Trip::class)
                ->findBy(['customer' => $user], ['id' => 'DESC']);
     dd($bookings);
```

It returns

[image]

[image]

**kindly help me out how to overcome this issue**

Comment: And just `return new JsonResponse($bookings);`?

Comment: it also returns empty array,

Answer (score 0):

You could use symfony component [Serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#serializing-an-object)

You could either turn your **array of objects** into an **array of array**:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ArrayDenormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

$serializer = new Serializer([new ArrayDenormalizer(), new DateTimeNormalizer(), new ObjectNormalizer(
            null,
            null,
            null,
            new ReflectionExtractor()
        ),],[ new JsonEncoder(),]);
$bookings = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Trip::class)
                ->findBy(['customer' => $this->getUser()], ['id' => 'DESC']);
$array = $serializer->normalize($bookings, 'array');
```

Or you could directly get a json using the serialize method:

```
 $json= $serializer->serialize($bookings, 'json');
```

If your entity has circular references, you can look into the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-circular-references) to handle it.

One way would be to add a callback method on how to handle objects, but It would be better if you read the documentation because the solution can vary depending on your entity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes is empty because json_encode supported array or object properties public, you can see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).
So You must parse $bookings.

JsonResponse use json_encode you can [see](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php#L128)

Example:

```js
$array = [];
$arrayBooking = [];

foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
    $arrayBooking['id'] = $booking->getId();
    $arrayBooking['toPlace'] = $booking->getToPlace();
    $array[] = $arrayBooking;
}

return new JsonResponse($array);
```

Or, You use Serializer  symfony component, as above.